# How to filter rows by equal values in different columns for groups in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, filter, group-by

I'm struggling on how can I filter my table when I have for the same company the same value in Cred and Debt. They need to be identic, as the toy example below.

Suppose the following table

```
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| Company | Cred     | Debt     | ID       |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| BFG     |       10 |         0|         1|
| AAA     |       11 |         0|         2|
| CCC     |        6 |         0|         3|
| BFG     |        0 |        13|         4|
| AAA     |        0 |        11|         5|
| CCC     |        0 |         7|         6|
| CCC     |        0 |         6|         7|
+---------+----------+----------+----------+


-- Desired result, as something like
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| Company | Cred     | Debt     | ID       |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| AAA     |       11 |         0|         2|
| CCC     |        6 |         0|         3|
| AAA     |        0 |        11|         5|
| CCC     |        0 |         6|         7|
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I thought of using their sum and filtering in the column the total that had equal values, grouping by total and company, but this strategy didn't work, since the company can have equal values in the debit column in different rows.

Any hint on how can I do that?

Comment: Simplify too much and you can easily go astray. What would you expect if the rows <AAA, 11, 0, 20> and <AAA, 0, 11, 21> existed? After all - the amount of a credit or debit can be easily and often duplicated over time for completely different transactions.

Comment: @SMor, in this case, these lines must also be considered.

Comment: That seems pretty obvious. Add that to your sample data, and then your desired output, and then explain the logic you think can be used to do your matching. I fear you have over-simplified your sample data and perhaps overlooked the complexity of ledger transactions that include credits and debits (note my assumption - perhaps this isn't ledger information at all). One frequently sees multiple credits and multiple debits for a given transaction - meaning you can't match on the individual amounts (i.e., you match on the total).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM tablename t2
  WHERE t2.Company = t1.Company AND t2.ID <> t1.ID
    AND t2.Cred = t1.Debt AND t2.Debt = t1.Cred
);
```

If `Cred` and `Debt` are always different in the same row you can remove the condition `AND t2.ID <> t1.ID`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.* 
from sometable a, sometable b
where a.id <> b.id
and a.company=b.company
and a.credit=b.debt
and a.debt = b.credit;
```